# Merge Sort - Wrong Output

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have just implemented Merge Sort in C. In terms of logic I think my code is right. Although, the output is wrong. And the output is not the number I have in the original array. That is what I find odd. Please help me. The output I receive is: -1 0 0 -1 0 4.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge (int right[], int left[], int elements[], int midValue) {

    int lengthL = midValue; /*tamanho do array da esquerda*/
    int lengthR = midValue - 1; /*tamanho do array da direita*/

    int i = 0; /*index do numero mais pequeno no array da esquerda*/
    int j = 0; /*index do numero mais pequeno no array da direita*/
    int k = 0; /*representa o index da posicao que precisa de ser preenchida no array original
               que neste caso é "elementos"*/

    while (i < lengthL && j < lengthR) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            elements[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else {
            elements[k] = right[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }


    /*estes dois while loops seguintes sao para as sobras em ambos
    os arrays. depois de sair do primeiro while loop que esta acima apenas um
    dos while loops a seguir serao executados pois apenas irá haver sobras em apenas um deles*/

    while (i < lengthL) {
        elements[k] = elements[i];
        i = i + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }

    while (j < lengthR) {
        elements[k] = elements[j];
        j = j + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }

}

void MergeSort (int elements[], int numberOfElements) {

    if (numberOfElements < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int midValue = numberOfElements / 2;

    int left[midValue];
    int right[midValue - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < midValue - 1; i = i + 1) {
        left[i] = elements[i];
    }

    for (int i = midValue; i < numberOfElements - 1; i = i + 1) {
        right[i] = elements[i];
    }

    MergeSort(left, midValue);
    MergeSort(right, midValue - 1);
    merge(left, right, elements, midValue);
}



int main() {

    int elements[6] = {2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 4};

    int numberOfElements = 6; /*número de elementos do array*/

    MergeSort(elements, numberOfElements);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i = i + 1) {
        printf("%d ",elements[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: This algorithm is *much* easier if you pass a sequence *length* rather than some `midValue`, and/or use pointer arithmetic for adjusting what is passed passed down the recursion calls.

Comment: If the input is OK and the output is not, then, despite your thinking the logic is OK, the program is telling you that your logic is not OK.  So, you need to start tracking down what is going wrong.  See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some information.  Either use the debugger to follow the flow, or add `printf()` statements to track what's happening.  Either way, you should keep going at that until you find (all) the problem(s).

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be multiple errors in your code.
For example, the input to `MergeSort` includes an array `elements` with
elements numbered 0, 1, ..., (numberOfElements - 1).  The loops that copy these elements from `elements` to the `left` and `right` arrays do not copy element number (midValue - 1) (too large to be copied by the `left` loop, too small to be copied by the `right` loop) nor do they copy element number (numberOfElements - 1).

Moreover, the second loop within `MergeSort` writes data to memory locations somewhere past the end of the space allocated for the `right` array, not in the correct places in the `right` array.
To correctly copy the second half of `elements`, element number midValue of `elements` should be copied to element number 0 of `right`.
Your code clearly does not do that.

When you pass the `left` and `right` arrays to `merge` near the end of `MergeSort`, however, `merge` treats the `left` array as if it contained midValue elements even though it contains only (midValue - 1) elements.

I think there's more but you have plenty of debugging to do already. Try printing out the input and output of each function to see if the functions are doing what you expect, or try smaller test cases (such as an array of length 2) and follow the logic of your program while you step through it in a debugger.